# Change <input type=text> font-size without changing its width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two text-boxes whose ratio of width is supposed to be 2:1, I can do that using flex. But when I change the font-size to 300% the width of the text boxes becomes equal.
How do I avoid that and keep the width in the ratio 2:1?

Here's the Code:

```css
input[type=text] {
  font-size: 300%;
}
#b4 {
  flex: 2;
}
#b2 {
  flex: 1;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="b4"></input>
  <input type="text" id="b2"></input>
</div>
```

Also, I don't want to set fixed width to any text-box.

Comment: @FalcoB: Was the original code like this before you converted it to a snippet? I don't understand how this can be seen as cleaner code than what I saw in the question while your edit was pending. The indentation is all over the place, there are extraneous blank lines in the HTML, and it's just ugly. Something doesn't seem right.

Comment: try giving `font-size` in `px` or in `em` except in `%`

Comment: The size is 1:2 in larger screens. Are you talking about the problem in small screens?

Comment: @Amitsingh I have to set the font-size in `%` and also setting the font-size in `px` or `em` doesn't work.

Comment: Unable to reproduce - http://jsfiddle.net/o29Lzsuf/

Comment: @Paulie_D Remove font-size:100% in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a Firefox issue as Chrome & IE11 do not have any problems. (Can't test on Safari as on Windows).

One solution, wrap the individual inputs in divs and flex *those* and set the inputs to be 100% wide.

Tested in FF 40 and seems to work.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwVgRX)

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=text] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.double {
  flex: 2;
}
.single {
  flex: 1;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.large input[type=text] {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="double">
    <input type="text" class="b4"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="single">
    <input type="text" class="b2"></input>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap large">

  <div class="double">
    <input type="text" class="b4"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="single">
    <input type="text" class="b2"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot even explain how happy I am to find this. I've been looking for a decent work around for a bit and tried many things myself, but I can't believe I didn't try this... Thank you

Answer (score 5):

This is a Firefox issue.

The best solution is adding a min-width for the input.

```
input{ min-width:0;}
```

OR

wrap the individual inputs in divs and flex those and set the inputs to be 100% wide.

Comment: Had this same issue in chrome on my android. min-width:0 fixed it. Thanks @Abhiman Ranaweera

Answer (score 0):

You can set fixed height & width to your textbox and set font size of your choice.

Example:

```
width: 180px;
font-size: 24px;
height: 25px;`
```

Comment: No. I don't want to set fixed dimensions.